# Browsers don't load all components from LinkedIn page

Tags: browser, html

I have persistent USB live Ubuntu. I've found that wherever browser i use some linkedin components are missing, most precisely - filter element which allows you to filter job offers, specify when added etc.(please compare image: "properly loaded tab in windows 10 - Firefox" vs "Ubuntu - Firefox" down below. This element has class="scaffold-layout-toolbar").

All browsers i have been using are freshly installed and updated, no adblocks, no browser protection, also cookies cleared.
I don`t have any customizations on my Ubuntu copy. I really don't have idea what is wrong. I was so happy seeing that my 12-year-old computer got significant performance improvement, but now this.

Ubuntu 22.04
Graphics card: Nvidia GeForce Gt 640 - installed recommended Nvidia driver-470 from Ubuntu "Software & Updates

Small update, yesterday I did test with USB live Kali Linux:

- Mozilla same behavior(doesn't work)
- Chromium is working

Ubuntu Opera, Ubuntu Chrome - doesn't work

Update:
got response from Linkedin team, it`s like I suspect:

> Reference # 230501-004719
> Status: Waiting For Information
>
> View your case(s) on our Help Center
> You may reply to this case for up to 14 days
> Response (05/02/2023 22:40 CST)
> Hello ,
>
> Thank you for your patience!
> We have an update from our internal team and they have confirmed that >Ubuntu is not a supported OS (Linux is not either), so unfortunately, >we would not be able to resolve this.
>
> Regards,
>
> Srikanth P S
> Member Support Consultant

Properly loaded tab in Windows 10 - Firefox:

[image: properly loaded tab in windows 10 - firefox]

Windows 10 selector:

[image: windows 10 selector]

Ubuntu - Firefox:

[image: Ubuntu - Firefox]

Ubuntu - Brave:

[image: Ubuntu - brave]

Ubuntu - Chromium:

[image: Ubuntu - Chromium]

Chromium dev tool but looks the same on every above:

[image: Chromium dev tool but looks the same on every above]

My Ubuntu version:

[image: My Ubuntu version]

Graphics card driver:

[image: Graphics card driver]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What video card? What driver for the video card? All o this info is needed. Please edit the question and add the info, not in comments. Not in links either in the body of the question.

Comment: Could you maybe be a bit more specific. What exactly isn't loading and how is this affecting your ability to use Ubuntu or the website? Use words to describe the problem, not a bunch of screenshots please.

Comment: I don't see that section either, but it's hard to debug without being on the exact same page as you. And it is entirely possible that LinkedIn decides to serve you parts of the page based on your user agent.

Comment: 't's hard to debug without being on the exact same page as you.' - you don`t have to, just click on job offers and choose anything, it`s always behave in same way. On my Android mobile, i have native linkedin app, and it has filtering too. i Have Kali Linux on other usb, so  i`ll try there maybe.